# HEAD requests vs getting only the `<head>` of a web page

Tags: html, http, html-parsing, http-head

I'm writing some link scraping code where I was hoping to grab only the `<head>` section of a given web page. Apparently I've been confused about what a HEAD request is, as I thought it was supposed to do exactly that. Instead, it just returns HTTP headers.

Is there a way to fetch just the `<head>` section of a given page, without getting the whole doc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no provision for that in the HTTP protocol (which doesn't know about HTML at all). You'll need to do a proper GET or POST, the use an HTML parser to extract the data you need.

The only thing you could do to limit what you get back is use the `Range` header, but that would just be guess-work on your part as to how much data you request.